# Measuring memory allocated in a C/C++ code block

Tags: c++, c, debugging, unix, memory

I'd like to measure the memory allocated by a block of C/C++ code that I did not write, while the program containing that block us running under Unix. Based on my research so far, I'm planning to use a debugger to break the execution before and after the code block, monitor the /proc/pid/status file at the breakpoints (where pid = process ID of the program containing the code block), and take the difference in one of the metrics reported in /proc/pid/status. Is this an accurate way to do this? I'm also not sure which metric from /proc/pid/status I should be using. Should I use VmRSS or VmSize?

Comment: Is that block of code part of a larger program that you are compiling yourself? If that's the case, instrumenting calls to `malloc()` (or linking against a library that does so) is generally the way to go.

Comment: If it is indeed code you wrote yourself, you can also put the function in question in its own section and export symbols with the start/end adress of said section.

Comment: Nevermind, i thought you want the size of the actual function

Comment: Unfortunately, the code block uses pre-compiled C++ libraries that I link against. Getting an estimate of the memory used by the libraries is the main motivation behind my question.

Comment: @FijoyVadakkumpadan That's not an issue. As soon as you provide your own `malloc()`, all calls to it (including pre-compiled libraries) will go through your implementation as long as said lib is not a dynamic object statically linked against libc (which it almost certainly isn't)

Comment: You can do that. Implement a wrapper function for malloc, have a function 'void malloc_start_count()' to start counting the allocated memory. Have a function 'long long malloc_stop_counting()' that returns the amount of memory allocated since the start_counting function was called. Call start_counting function before, call stop_counting function after calling the library function in question. i guess thats about as simple as it gets.

Comment: You can't accurately assess program heap usage by looking at VM RSS, since freed heap memory is never returned to the OS. So VM RSS represents the program's peak heap usage, not the current one.

Comment: Did you look at `mtrace`?

Comment: valgrind's *massif* tool might be useful here.  https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'll be taking a look at mtrace and massif.